# SetInterval in Context Provider running two times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this below code in global.js running two times when i run my react app, not confirm the reason. Thanks in  advance. I have use setinterval to test, and intervals are running always two times. May be I am not initialization correctly. I have removed strict mode but still facing the problem, i just want to implement global variable to maintain single variable to components, and allowing it to change them from any component

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {NameProvider} from './Global';
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  
    <NameProvider>
    <App />
    </NameProvider>
  
);
reportWebVitals();
```

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import ComOne from './ComOne'
import ComTwo from './ComTwo';
function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ComOne />
      <ComTwo />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ComOne.js

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import {useName} from './Global'
const ComOne = () => {

      const {setName} = useName();
      useEffect(()=>{
            setName('ASD')
      },[])
      //console.log('XYZ')

      return (
            <div>COMONE</div>
      );
};

export default ComOne;
```

ComTwo.js

```
import React from 'react';
class ComTwo extends React.Component {

      render() {
            return (
                  <div>COMTWO</div>
            ) 
      }
}

export default ComTwo;
```

Global.js

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

// Step 1: Create a Context
const NameContext = React.createContext();

// Step 2: Create a Provider Component
export const NameProvider = ({ children }) => {
  let [name, setName] = useState('');

  let counter = 0;

  useEffect(()=>{
      setInterval(()=>{
            counter++;
            //console.log(counter);
      },3000);
  },[])
  console.log('ABCX')
  return (
    <NameContext.Provider value={{ name, setName}}>
      {children}
    </NameContext.Provider>
  );
};

// Step 3: Create a Custom Hook to Access the Context
export const useName = () => {
  return useContext(NameContext);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In React `StrictMode` renders components twice on the development mode, on production they render only once, you do not have to worry about it

Comment: *"you do not have to worry about it"* - Maybe, maybe not.  But either way, that `useEffect` should really be returning a cleanup function which clears that interval.

Comment: The point of "running twice" (actually: unmounting and remounting the component) in development mode is _so that you don't do incorrect things like this_. The idea is that this will make you notice your mistake. You _do_ have to worry about it - you should fix the mistake so the code behaves correctly regardless of whether it's the initial mount or a remount! Otherwise, things will break some day later when your component gets remounted and you never tested the case before...

Comment: Hi, can you please look into updated question.